# Extract elements and text out of one paragraph and insert into another

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph full of YouTube videos, and I'm trying to extract those including any text before or after into a chronological succession of new paragraphs. Ie.:

```
<div>
    <p>before <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> middle 1 <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> middle 2 <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> after</p>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div>
    <p>before</p>
    <p><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a></p>
    <p>middle 1</p>
    <p><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a></p>
    <p><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a></p>
    <p>middle 2</p>
    <p><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a></p>
    <p>after</p>
</div>
```

What I have, unfortunately, messes up the order and creates separate divs for each YouTube as opposed to gathering everything into a single div.

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/kyrmq3cn/

```
$(function () {
    $('.youtube').each(function () {
        var elem = $(this),
            parent = elem.parent(),
            parentContainer = parent.parent(),
            content = parent.contents(),
            index = content.index(this),
            before = content.slice(0, index),
            after = content.slice(index + 1),
            beforeText = before.text(),
            afterText = after.text();

        var beforeOut = $('<p/>').text(beforeText || ''),
            youtubeOut = $('<p/>').append(elem.clone()),
            afterOut = $('<p/>').text(afterText || ''),

            resultDiv = $('<div/>');

        resultDiv.append(beforeOut);
        resultDiv.append(youtubeOut);
        resultDiv.append(afterOut);

        resultDiv.css('border', '5px solid blue');
        resultDiv.insertAfter(parentContainer);

        parentContainer.css('opacity', '0.2')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Iterate through the contents of `div p` and wrap each in a `p` element, then finally remove the empty `div p` -- first element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div p').contents().each(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').append( $('<p/>').html( this )[0] );
  });
  $('div p:empty').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <p>before <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> middle 1 <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> middle 2 <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5z69NLAdCo"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/a5z69NLAdCo/hqdefault.jpg"></a> after</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sweet! I forgot to mention though that this should only be applied to paragraphs with `.youtube`. Here's the original fiddle covering all the possible scenarios: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/woL14c9f/. If we could truly do something as simple as yours that would be amazing!

Comment: This is basically for forum posts incase users add inline stuff I'd like a neat way of separating them. A div may have multiple paragraphs of user text and it should not touch those, just YouTubes and any potential stuff around them.

Comment: You would just have to change `div p` to `div p:has(a.youtube)` ---> http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/woL14c9f/2/ and one other change: ---> In `each()` `$('div')` to `$(this).closest('div')`

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my question a little - any chance we could make it work for such a scenario? Sorry, I should have explained myself better the first time.

Comment: It might be better to restore the original question and ask a new question. That way all these comments would make sense .. in the context of the original question and someone else may benefit from it.